# Grid won't load when toggled on

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, 2d

Can someone explain why this isn't loading when I toggle on. Whenever I click the menu UI button for toggle grid, the console prints out the right boolean values but the grid won't draw.

I tried the repaint method and tried calling the method that loaded the grid again as well.

```
    private boolean toggleGrid = false;

public Editor() {

    width = DEFAULT_WIDTH;
    height = DEFAULT_HEIGHT;

    setTitle("Map Editor");
    setSize(width, height);

    mouse = new Mouse();

    addMouseListener(mouse);
    addMouseMotionListener(mouse);

    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    loadMenuUI();
    loadTileContainer();
    loadEditContainer();

}

private void loadMenuUI(){

    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    setJMenuBar(menuBar);

    JMenu mnFile = new JMenu("File");
    menuBar.add(mnFile);

    JMenuItem mntmNewProject = new JMenuItem("New Project");
    mntmNewProject.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('N', InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    mnFile.add(mntmNewProject);

    JMenuItem mntmSave = new JMenuItem("Save...");
    mntmSave.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('S', Event.CTRL_MASK));
    mnFile.add(mntmSave);

    JMenuItem mntmLoad = new JMenuItem("Load...");
    mntmLoad.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('O', Event.CTRL_MASK));
    mnFile.add(mntmLoad);

    mnFile.addSeparator();

    JMenuItem mntmExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    mntmExit.setAccelerator(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('N', InputEvent.CTRL_MASK));
    mnFile.add(mntmExit);

    JMenu mnOptions = new JMenu("Options");
    menuBar.add(mnOptions);

    JMenuItem mntmChangeGridSize = new JMenuItem("Change Grid Size");
    mnOptions.add(mntmChangeGridSize);

    JMenuItem mntmChangeScreenSize = new JMenuItem("Change Screen Size");
    mnOptions.add(mntmChangeScreenSize);

    JMenuItem mntmToggleGrid = new JMenuItem("Toggle Grid");
    mntmToggleGrid.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(toggleGrid) toggleGrid = false;
            else {
                toggleGrid = true;
                repaint();
            }
        }
    });
    mnOptions.add(mntmToggleGrid);
}

private void loadTileContainer(){
    tileContainer = new JPanel(new GridLayout(20,20));
    tileContainer.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    tileContainer.setBounds(0, 0, width - 15, height - 200);
    tileContainer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));

    if(toggleGrid){
        System.out.println("Working");
        for(int i = 0; i < 400; i++){
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
                          label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            tileContainer.add(label);
        }
    }

    contentPane.add(tileContainer);
}
```

Comment: Do `revalidate()` instead of `repaint()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once this method is called, it's over, it's done:

```
private void loadTileContainer(){
    tileContainer = new JPanel(new GridLayout(20,20));
    tileContainer.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    tileContainer.setBounds(0, 0, width - 15, height - 200);
    tileContainer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(2,2,2,2));

    if(toggleGrid){
        System.out.println("Working");
        for(int i = 0; i < 400; i++){
            JLabel label = new JLabel();
            label.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
            tileContainer.add(label);
        }
    }

    contentPane.add(tileContainer);
}
```

---

Then your menu code:

```
mntmToggleGrid.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(toggleGrid) toggleGrid = false;
        else {
            toggleGrid = true;
            repaint();
        }
    }
});
```

---

Simply setting toggleGrid to true from within an ActionListener will not magically call the `loadTileContainer()` method again, so it should come as no surprise that your ActionListener has no effect. Instead you will want to extract the code from the if block and put it in its own method, one that can be called from the action listener when needed.

Then after changing a container's contents, you will need to call `revalidate()` and then `repaint()` on the container.

Much better still however is for you to swap components using a CardLayout. The [CardLayout tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) will show you how.